# Mobile: How to indicate presence of landscape mode and expandable elements?

Tags: mobile, tables

### Problem:

My company has a desktop website to display reports, and now also a mobile website. The reports there have only 3 columns in portrait mode to keep it clean, but show extra columns when you switch to landscape mode. However, when I track how the users use the site, literally nobody uses the landscape mode, but rather go to the desktop site when they can't find the details they want.

Also the rows expand when you click on them to show **all** the details, but nobody seems to have found it so far...

### Question(s):

- How to indicate landscape mode is available for more details?
- How to indicate rows can expand upon tap?

Currently I see no other solution than showing a one-time popup, but I'm sure there must be other, more elegant ways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is hidden, the first thing comes up to my mind is to display a self-explanatory icon. Like this:

[image]

About the rows, you seem to have the same problem: the function is hidden. Try to use the same design rules that are commonly used for Call to Action buttons (for example use visual affordances to look the row as it was something "tapable"). You can find many websites that show how to design a good Call to Action.

If you already tried these solutions, a hint or a modal with a tutorial on first access could also help.

Comment: I think I'll just show a small notification the first time they visit the page with the icon you proposed and a sentence of information about what it does